# Sorting nodes with xslt not working

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon

I have the following xml and xsl files and I am trying to sort the `CARTONDETAIL` nodes, but leave the rest of the document as the original.

So far, the top part of my document gets copied over, everything before `CARTONDETAIL`. After that I just get a lot of empty `<CARTONDETAIL>` tags, like I am creating an endless loop, because the document never puts the closing brackets at the end nor the other `HEADER` instance. In the input file I have two instances of the `HEADER` tree, but I don't see any traces of the second one in my output file.

I am using saxon to parse the documents.

Any help is greatly appreciated.. Thanks all!

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TRUCKSHIPUPLOAD>
    <HEADER>
        <WH>WH1</WH>
        <OWN>FakeOwner</OWN>
        <ORD>1035710</ORD>
        <RELEASE_NUM>1</RELEASE_NUM>
        <ORDER_LINE/>
        <TRUCK>0222001406</TRUCK>
        <ORDERING>1</ORDERING>
        <TRAILER_ID/>
        <WAREHOUSE_ID>UDS01</WAREHOUSE_ID>
        <OWNER_ID>CAYRE</OWNER_ID>
        <IF_SEQ_NUM>222001406</IF_SEQ_NUM>
        <IF_STATUS/>
        <IF_ERROR_MSG/>
        <ORDER_ID>1035710</ORDER_ID>
        <STAT_DATE/>
        .........
        <CARTON>
            <WH>WH1</WH>
            <OWN>FakeOwner</OWN>
            <ORD>1035710</ORD>
            <RELEASE_NUM>1</RELEASE_NUM>
            <ORDER_LINE/>
            <TRUCK>0222001406</TRUCK>
            <ORDERING>4</ORDERING>
            <TRAILER_ID/>
            ....
            <CARTONDETAIL>
                <WH>WH1</WH>
                <OWN>FakeOwner</OWN>
                <ORD>1035710</ORD>
                <RELEASE_NUM>1</RELEASE_NUM>
                <ORDER_LINE>4</ORDER_LINE>
                <TRUCK>0222001406</TRUCK>
                <TRAILER_ID/>
                <WAREHOUSE_ID>WH1</WAREHOUSE_ID>
                <OWNER_ID>FakeOwner</OWNER_ID>
                <IF_SEQ_NUM/>
                <IF_STATUS/>
                <IF_ERROR_MSG/>
                <ORDER_ID>1035710</ORDER_ID>
                <STAT_DATE/>
                ...
            </CARTONDETAIL>

            <CARTONDETAIL>
                <WH>WH1</WH>
                <OWN>FakeOwner</OWN>
                <ORD>1035710</ORD>
                <RELEASE_NUM>1</RELEASE_NUM>
                <ORDER_LINE>8</ORDER_LINE>
                <TRUCK>0222001406</TRUCK>
                <TRAILER_ID/>
                <WAREHOUSE_ID>WH1</WAREHOUSE_ID>
                <OWNER_ID>FakeOwner</OWNER_ID>
                <IF_SEQ_NUM/>
                <IF_STATUS/>
                <IF_ERROR_MSG/>
                <ORDER_ID>1035710</ORDER_ID>
                <STAT_DATE/>
                ...
            </CARTONDETAIL>
            <CARTONDETAIL>
                <WH>WH1</WH>
                <OWN>FakeOwner</OWN>
                <ORD>1035710</ORD>
                <RELEASE_NUM>1</RELEASE_NUM>
                <ORDER_LINE>2</ORDER_LINE>
                <TRUCK>0222001406</TRUCK>
                <TRAILER_ID/>
                <WAREHOUSE_ID>WH1</WAREHOUSE_ID>
                <OWNER_ID>FakeOwner</OWNER_ID>
                <IF_SEQ_NUM/>
                <IF_STATUS/>
                <IF_ERROR_MSG/>
                <ORDER_ID>1035710</ORDER_ID>
                <STAT_DATE/>
                ...
            </CARTONDETAIL>

        </CARTON>
    </HEADER>
</TRUCKSHIPUPLOAD>
```

XSL:

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

           <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
            <xsl:template match="CARTONDETAIL">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="//CARTONDETAIL">
                        <xsl:sort select="ORDER_LINE" data-type="number"/>
                    </xsl:apply-templates>
                </xsl:copy> 
            </xsl:template>
            <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:template>
        </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think instead of

```
        <xsl:template match="CARTONDETAIL">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="//CARTONDETAIL">
                    <xsl:sort select="ORDER_LINE" data-type="number"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </xsl:copy> 
        </xsl:template>
```

you want

```
        <xsl:template match="CARTON">
            <xsl:copy>
              <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="boolean(self::CARTONDETAIL)">
               <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
                 <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()">
                    <xsl:sort select="ORDER_LINE" data-type="number"/>
                 </xsl:apply-templates>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                   <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:copy> 
        </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks all for the great answers, I went with Matin's solution. You guys are great..

Answer (score 0):

First thing: you **do** have an infinite loop here:

```
<xsl:template match="CARTONDETAIL">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//CARTONDETAIL">
     ...
```

Now, assuming you want to sort the `CARTONDETAIL` nodes within their parent `CARTON`, try:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="CARTON">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()">
            <xsl:sort select="ORDER_LINE" data-type="number"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Technically, infinite recursion rather than an infinite loop, but it amounts to the same thing.

Comment: @MichaelKay Isn't infinite recursion [a special case of an infinite loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_loop#Infinite_recursion)?

Comment: Not in my view. With an infinite loop, the entire state of the system repeats itself an infinite number of times. With infinite recursion, the same state never occurs twice. They are both special cases of non-terminating programs.

Answer (score 0):

Copy all nodes and sort CARTONDETAIL  with respect to ORDER_LINE, hope that this is what you wanted.

```
       <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
        <xsl:template match="CARTON">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="CARTONDETAIL">
                    <xsl:sort select="ORDER_LINE" data-type="number"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </xsl:copy> 
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What happens to the other (not CARTONDETAIL) children of CARTON?